# "Structures Get Copied, Arrays Get Aliased " what does this mean?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I was reading Klemens, Ben. 21st Century C: C Tips from the New School  and I was stopped by sentence "Structures Get Copied, Arrays Get Aliased", and I didn't get it quite well, neither was the example clear for me. Can anyone explain it ?

the Example codes

```
    #include <assert.h>

typedef struct{
    int a, b;
    double c, d;
    int *efg;
} demo_s;
int main(){
    demo_s d1 = {.b=1, .c=2, .d=3, .efg=(int[]){4,5,6}};
    demo_s d2 = d1;

    d1.b=14;            
    d1.c=41;
    d1.efg[0]=7;

    assert(d2.a==0);    
    assert(d2.b==1);
    assert(d2.c==2);
    assert(d2.d==3);
    assert(d2.efg[0]==7);
}
```

Klemens, Ben. 21st Century C: C Tips from the New School . O'Reilly Media. Kindle Edition.

```
#include <assert.h>

int main(){
    int abc[] = {0, 1, 2};
    int *copy = abc;

    copy[0] = 3;
assert(abc[0]==3); 
}
```

Klemens, Ben. 21st Century C: C Tips from the New School . O'Reilly Media. Kindle Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ths assignment:

`demo_s d2 = d1;`

in first example actualy COPIED the contents of the struct. So this means that if the original struct changes some value this will NOT be reflected in the copy (they do not share the same reference) nor vice-versa.

On the other hand for arrays the assignment:

`int *copy = abc;`

only assigns the reference of the array to copy, but does NOT copy the contents of the array. So this means that if the original array changes some values the copied reference (since they refer to same reference) will reflect the changes as well (or vice-versa). In a sense (see also comments below this answer) the `copy` is another name for `abc` they refer to the same object, it is an alias if you like, hence the explanation

The assertions on the examples illustrate this feature of the C language.

**Note** that on first example with struct, the `efg` field is a pointer to an array, and this is also copied but it copies the reference, so this reflects the changes made to field of original struct.

Comment: `only copies the name` WRONG. Please show me how to retrieve this name

Comment: @P__J__, it is a figure of speech, a metaphor. The pointer value is copied, the reference

Comment: int *copy id not the array so the example does not have any sense

Comment: is not copied - it is assigned

Comment: @P__J__ actualy pointer values are copied since after all they are memory values. But this means that the same memory position is stored in two different variables, so they refer to exact same object

Comment: no they **are not** stored in two memory locations. array is not the pointer. after this assignment only `copy` stores the reference to the array.

Comment: @P__J__ what do you mean array is not the pointer? `abc` is the pointer at start of the array

Comment: no it is not. It decays to the pointer but it is not the reference. abc && &abc reference the same memory location, only the type differs. So it is not the pointer like `copy`. \

Comment: @P__J__, this is correct, by an abuse of language I refered to it as pointer. It decays to the pointer is correct